# If a certain word is not before the search word then add to list python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, sentence

I would like the program to detect whether a certain word is before the search word and if it is not to add it to a list.

This is what I have come up with myself:

```
sentence = "today i will take my dog for a walk, tomorrow i will not take my dog for a walk"

all = ["take", "take"] 

all2= [w for w in all if not(re.search(r'not' + w + r'\b', sentence))]
print(all2)
```

The excpected output is ["take"], but it remains the same with ["take, "take]

Comment: The search word in this example is `not`?

Comment: @debuggingXD in this case the search word is w (every word in the list - all)

Comment: 1) add space before `not` 2) you won't get the expected result cause `re.search` will search through the whole sentence each time

Comment: why list `all` has repeated value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oh, okay! So, is there another way to solve this?

Comment: you may use `findall` if you try to find the word that doesn't contain `not` before. Like: `re.findall(r'(?i)((?:\w+\s)?{0})(?=.*not)'.format('take'), sentence)`

Answer (score 1):

Watch how it should be formulated: *gather all `take` word occurrences that aren't preceded with word `not`*:

```
import re

sentence = "today i will take my dog for a walk, tomorrow i will not take my dog for a walk"
search_word = 'take'
all_takes_without_not = re.findall(fr'(?<!\bnot)\s+({search_word})\b', sentence)
print(all_takes_without_not)
```

The output:

```
['take']
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to first convert you sentence to a list of words.

```
from itertools import chain

# Get individual words from the string
words = sentence.split()

# Create an iterator which yields the previous word at each position
previous = chain([None], words)

output = [word for prev, word in zip(previous, words) if word=='take' and prev != 'not']
```